# Parallel job execution by setting job module count in Spring XD?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

Since besides stream module, Spring-XD slap support to set module count number for batch jobs. For example, module.myjob.count=3. What will happen if the job is deployed in this way?

1. Will the job be deployed on 3 different containers?
2. Will the 3 copies of deployment execute in parallel? Does each copy execute independently without any interaction or extra orchestration (say, with a master)?
3. Can I assign different job parameters for each of the copy? How can I do it in Spring-XD?

Thanks in advance,
T.S.Tao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes; unless you create a [partitioned job](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_deployment_manifest_support_for_job) in which case all instances participate in the job partition executions, with one instance controlling the overall job execution.
3. The instances will compete for work; in general job launches will be round-robin distributed; there is no way to control which instance gets a launch request; to do that you would have to deploy different job definitions and target their deployments for specific container groups.

Comment: Thanks, given my expectation on the real parallelism, I will go with the "different job definitions" solution.